# My submit button won't register my information in my HTML form

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello and thanks for reading already.

I've encountered a problem while creating a login system. Due to styling reasons have I been forced to create 2 different forms. One with Email and Password. Another with the submit button.

Due to the Submit button not being in the same form as email and password, it will not register the information when used.

The code looks like the following:

```
    <section class="loginGrid">

  <form class="loginInfo" action="includes/login.includes.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="password">
    <br> <br>
    <label> <a class="forgotPassword" href="forgotpwd.php"> Forgotten password? </a> </label>
  </form>

  <form class="loginbtn" action="includes/login.includes.php" method="post">
    <button class="ctaButton" type="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
    <br> <br>
    <label> <a class="notSignedUp" href="signup.php"> Don't have an account yet? </a> </label>
  </form>

</section>
```

... And here is the following in another php file.

```
<?php

session_start();

$DBserver = "localhost";
$DBusername = "root";
$DBpassword = "";
$DBdatabase = "amigo_db";

$conn = mysqli_connect($DBserver, $DBusername, $DBpassword, $DBdatabase);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
  exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!isset($_POST['Email'], $_POST['Password'])) {
  header("Location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields");
  exit();
}

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Email, Password FROM users WHERE Email = ?')) {
use "s"
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['Email']);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($Email, $Password);
  $stmt->fetch();

    if ($_POST['Password'] === $Password) {

      session_regenerate_id();
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
      $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['Email'];
      echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
   }

 else {
      echo 'Incorrect password!';
  }


} else {
  echo 'Incorrect username!';
}


   $stmt->close();
  }
```

Thank you for reading it through. Hoping to meet a solution here.

Edit:

The scss file:

```
@import '_basics.scss';
@import '_variables.scss';

.loginGrid {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

}

.loginInfo {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;

  & > input {
    width: 80vw;
    opacity: 50%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

   & > label {
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 14px;

     & > a {
       color: #000000;
     }
   }
}

.loginbtn {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;

  & > .ctaButton {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 10vw;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, $gradientRed 0%, $gradientOrange 75%, $gradientPeach 100%);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 30vw;
    border-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  & > label {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;

    & > a {
      color: #000000;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the styling reason that makes you put a submit button in a complete different form ?

Comment: If the submit button is not in the same form you will need JS to do that.

Comment: Please post the css and a pic of the desired output; resolving your css issue would be the best way to resolve this

Comment: I have added the scss file. The essential is that I want to place the Email and Password in one position while the submit/Log in button in another.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove one form and use only one form when both form actions are same like following

```
 <section class="loginGrid">

  <form class="loginInfo " id="loginInfo" action="includes/login.includes.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="password">
    <br> <br>
    <label> <a class="forgotPassword" href="forgotpwd.php"> Forgotten password? </a> </label>

    <button class="ctaButton" type="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
    <br> <br>
    <label> <a class="notSignedUp" href="signup.php"> Don't have an account yet? </a> </label>
  </form>

</section>
```

Comment: As I wish to place the submit/login in button at the bottom of the page while the Email and password on the center of the page this is not the answer unfortunatly.